# NullPointerException when acting on a View

Tags: java, android, view, nullpointerexception

For some reason I'm getting a nullPointerException when working with any new View I place in my XML. The view type (TextView, EditText, etc) doesn't matter. Any views I originally had work - it's isolated to any newly added views.

I've tried cleaning the project numerous times, deleted the entire XML file, restarted eclipse, then re-pasted the XML back into a new file, no luck. Appears to be similar as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687371/nullpointerexception-thrown-in-eclipse-when-trying-to-open-android-xml-view) question, but nothing has gotten this working.

I really don't want to have to re-create the entire project, but I'm not sure what else to do if recreating the XML and cleaning isn't enough.

Code is as follows:

```
XML
...
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/dlg_add_proj_test_text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Test Text" />
...

Activity
...
public void fireDlg() {
  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_add_proj);
  dialog.setTitle("Add Project");

  //Other previous views
  TextView newTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dlg_add_proj_test_text);
  newTxtView.setText("New Text"); //Null Pointer Here

}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should be using `dialog.findViewById(R.id.dlg_add_proj_test_text)` instead of just `findViewById`. The `findViewById` uses the activity's method while `dialog.findViewById` uses the method in the dialog.

Comment: Wow... and that's what I get for late night coding with beer. Much thanks.